# Disabling taskbar after changing ViewController in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, tabs, disable

I would like to disable the task bar after changing the ViewController programmatically. I have a hover button. After a click on it this code is called to change the ViewController:

```
self.navigationController?.setViewControllers([lvc!], animated: true)
```

This works well. After the change I am calling the viewDidLoad method which is also called (checked the console).
The code is like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
}
```

The button is in the HomeView. If I am calling `self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = false`
 in the viewDidLoad method of the HomeView the tab bar is disabled. I am using NavigationController for presenting the different Views.

Any idea why the tab bar is not disabled and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
_ = tabBarController?.tabBar.items?.compactMap { $0.isEnabled = false }
```

Comment: Simple and just brilliant. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the delegate method `shouldSelectViewController` of the `UITabbarControllerDelegate`. This delegate asks if the user can select the view controller, in simple words.

See the Apple documentation [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontrollerdelegate/1621166-tabbarcontroller)

Use it like this:

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    If homeControllerIsDoingSomething {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```